# Problemas con el modulo bcryptjs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, bcryptjs

tengo un problema, estoy creando una api con NodeJS y MongoDB la cual tiene permisos y autentificación, aparte de eso estoy usando bcryptjs el cual es usado para encriptar contraseñas, el problema es que al momento de enviar la petición post me está trayendo el objeto incompleto y el faltante es la contraseña encriptada, a continuación coloco el código:

Aquí el controlador.

```
export const signUp = async (req, res) => {
    const {username, email, password, roles} = req.body;

    const newUser = new User({
        username,
        email,
        password: User.encryptPassword(password)
    })

    console.log(newUser);


    res.json('signup');
}
```

Aquí doy la estructura como tal de como quiero que me llegue el objeto y aparte utilizo el modulo bcryptjs y creo una función.

```
import {Schema, model} from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    roles: [{
        ref: "Role",
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
})

userSchema.statics.encryptPassword = async (password) => {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    return await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
}
     
export default model('User', userSchema);
```

Aquí anexo un código que cree para los roles aunque aun no está terminado pero lo agrego por si se preguntan de donde tome la palabra `Role`

```
 import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
    
    const roleSchema = new Schema({
        name: String
    }, {
        versionKey: false
    })
    
    export default model('Role', roleSchema);


y ya por ultimo les comparto la petición y como llega en la consola.

POST http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signup
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "SebasGames97",
    "email": "sebastianrobayog@gmail.com",
    "password": "callefalsa123"
}

{
  username: 'SebasGames97',
  email: 'sebastianrobayog@gmail.com',
  roles: [],
  _id: new ObjectId("61df74bd686c556b2efc468c")
}
POST /api/auth/signup 200 3.190 ms - 8
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré cual es la solución y me falto agregarle el `await`

```
export const signUp = async (req, res) => {
    const {username, email, password, roles} = req.body;

    const newUser = new User({
        username,
        email,
        password: await User.encryptPassword(password)
    })

    console.log(newUser);


    res.json('signup');
}
```

luego de eso funciona bien

```
{
  username: 'SebasGames97',
  email: 'sebastianrobayog@gmail.com',
  password: '$2a$10$ieWN2E4U7JYrd5E6IN3Xf.pDv1FyyaJCDJtPmEd4O4dIWdcUlCrwe',
  roles: [],
  _id: new ObjectId("61df77bcd10a6af0ab895d41")
}
POST /api/auth/signup 200 100.527 ms - 8
```